# Trying to set a dynamic url as backgroundImage in vuejs in v-for

Tags: vue.js, url, background-image

Currently trying to add a dynamic url to my background image inside select option. But it seems breaking, not sure how that comes and how to fix this. Looking for different combinations like ` or ' and even ". But really confused.

```js
 <select v-model.lazy="countryCode" @change="handleChange" class="select-field height-select-input select-width">
            <option v-for="(country, index) in checkCountryName"
              :key="index"
              :value="country.country_code"
              :selected="index === 0"
              :data-value="country.city_name"

               :style="{backgroundImage: 'url('https://www.countryflags.io/' +  {{country.country_code}} + '/flat/64.png')'}"
            >
                            
              {{ country.country_code }}
            </option>
          </select>
```

Comment: You shouldn’t be using handlebars in your v-bind directive. Abstract that into a method instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
:style="`backgroundImage: url('https://www.countryflags.io/${country.country_code}/flat/64.png')`"
```

Comment: Property or method "url" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

Comment: Not working unfortunately....[Vue warn]: Property or method "url" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

Comment: just remove curly braces
last one from me

Comment: curly braces is needed

Comment: ``` <div v-bind:style="{ color: activeColor, fontSize: fontSize + 'px' }"></div>
data: {
  activeColor: 'red',
  fontSize: 30
}  ```

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html
follow this link

Comment: <div v-bind:style="styleObject"></div>
data: {
  styleObject: {
    color: 'red',
    fontSize: '13px'
  }
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217565/discussion-between-md-jahidul-islam-and-frontend-employee).

Comment: Seems working, but how can I show it in vue select option

Answer (score -1):

Is that the exact code you are using? If so, it looks like the issue is within the quotation marks on your url request.

You have

```
:style="{backgroundImage: 'url('https://www.countryflags.io/{{country.country_code}}/flat/64.png')'}"
```

Remove the quotes around the url and it should work

```
:style="{backgroundImage: 'url(https://www.countryflags.io/{{country.country_code}}/flat/64.png)'}"
```

Comment: But the country.country_code is something that comes from the v-for output......it is a dynamic part that needs to be concatenated.